# Picard method to solve a diferential equation

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, integration, derivatives, numerical-methods

I have to obtain by Picard method the solution to this problem.
$$x'=x+t, x(0)=x_0$$

doing $$x_j=x_0 + \int_{0}^{t} f(s,x_{j-1}(s))ds$$
i have obtain $$x_{j}=x_0(1+...+\dfrac{t^j}{j!})+\dfrac{t^{j+1}}{j+1!}$$
but i dont know how to continue because the first part i think links with $x_0e^{t}$ doing the limit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the recursion you've obtained isn't quite right. In particular I think it should be
$$x_j=x_0\left(1+t+\cdots+\frac{t^j}{j!}\right)+\frac{1}{2}t^2+\frac{1}{6}t^3+\cdots+\frac{t^{j+1}}{(j+1)!}.$$
In particular I'm guessing that you ended up taking
$$x_j=x_0+\int_0^tx_{j-1}(s)\,ds$$
instead of
$$x_j=x_0+\int_0^t\big(s+x_{j-1}(s)\big)\,ds,$$
because that's a mistake I also made at first, also ending up with your equation.

Anyway recognize the equation above as
$$x_j=x_0\sum_{k=0}^j\frac{t^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^{j+1}\frac{t^k}{k!}-1-t,$$
and then it should be easy to figure out the answer.

Comment: yes!! i think that was my mistake you are right  :)any idea of what is the result of that sum or i can solve the equation by my way and it must be the same result?Thanks

Comment: ok,i have it, $x_{0}e^{t}+e^{t}-t-1$ thank you very much :)